# pyinstaller not working with praw library

Tags: python, pyinstaller, praw

I don't why but it seems that only praw library is not working. I've tried running different projects with other libraries but they seem to work. Does anyone know what's the problem?
[error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhWtR.png)

Code im using:

```
import praw
import time
import os


lst = []

reddit = **all reddit credentials**




all = reddit.subreddit("all")
for i in all.search('url:"https://discord.gg/"',sort = 'new'):
    x = str(i.subreddit)
    lst.append(x)


for line in lst:
        if 'u_' in line:
             lst.remove(line)



temp_list = []
for i in lst:
    if i not in temp_list:
        temp_list.append(i)


lst = temp_list



for juris in lst:
    
    print(juris)


print('')
print('')

os.system("pause")
```

Comment: it looks like you are using auto-py-to-exe.... either way create a [mre]

Comment: Just updated my post.

Comment: Ill post a step by step to getting it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using windows, so use your operating systems compatible alternative for any of the commands below.

##### Steps to solve:

1. create a new directory and `cd` into it
2. `python -m venv venv` & `venv\scripts\activate`
3. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller praw`
4. copy your script into the folder and call `pyinstaller -F myscript.py`

This will create a `.spec` file.

Make this alteration to the `datas` parameter on line number 11 in the spec file.

`myscript.spec`

```
...
...
    datas=[("./venv/Lib/site-packages/praw","./praw")],
...
...
```

5. run `pyinstaller myscript.spec`

All done... now the executable that it creates should work